# An Application of Minkowski's theorem

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

There is a problem that I am sure involves Minkowski's theorem, but not sure how to construct the appropriate lattice:

Suppose $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $b^2-4ac<0$. Show that there exists $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2-0$ such that $ax^2+bxy+cy^2\leq \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{4ac-b^2}$.

Here is my reasoning: it seems that this is the case when $n=2$ and $r_2=1$ in the Minkowski's Constant $\mu_K=\frac{n!}{n^n}(\frac{4}{\pi})^{r_2}\sqrt{|\Delta_K|}$ and $b^2-4ac$ is the discriminant of polynomial.

But I don't know how to construct a lattice in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ so that I can use Minkowski's theorem. Could someone give me a hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $ax^2+bxy+cy^2 = \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{4ac-b^2}$ is an ellipse. Calculate its area.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has non-real roots, that are algebraic numbers. 
The lattice generated by $1$ and $\sqrt \Delta $   if the discriminant is 2 or 3 modulo 4, or the lattice generated by $1$ and $\frac {1+\sqrt \Delta}{2}$  otherwise.  One can see for example Michael Artin's ALGEBRA for details about imaginary quadratic fields and the lattices arising as  ideals in their ring of integers.

Comment: Yeah I know this is the ring of integers, but I cannot see the relation between this and what the problem asks me to do... $\Delta$ here may not be square-free, and it seems that I should construct a ideal of the ring of integers...